# Can any one help me on angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when i am loging to admin section . i am getting some issue like `{{vm.error}}`.

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 bg-success">
    <h2>Admin Login</h2>
    <div ng-show="vm.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{vm.error}}</div>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.admin()" role="form" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username" required />
            <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password" required />
            <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
            <img ng-if="vm.dataLoading" src="" />
            <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-danger">Register</a>
            <a href="#/forgetpassword"> Forget Password </a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller admin

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('AdminController', AdminController);

AdminController.$inject = ['$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'FlashService'];
function AdminController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.admin = admin;

    (function initController() {
        // reset login status
        AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
    })();

    function admin() 
    {
        vm.dataLoading = true;
        AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password, function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                FlashService.Error(response.message);
                vm.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    };
}
```

})();

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: you want controller code??

Comment: You are only showing an error message... In order to help you, you have to show what code you're trying that isn't working.

Comment: @ maxton and @Anik Islam Abhi. please check above...

Comment: you should have `ng-controller="AdminController as vm"` on your page

Answer (score 0):

You get `{{vm.error}}` displayed on screen because angular doesn't know anything about it. Your controller only sets `vm.admin`, so `vm.error` is not known.

It looks like you're setting your error into `FlashService`. You need to get the error out of there somehow - it won't magically put it into vm.error for you.

It appears that you're trying to copy the login approach presented here: https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example

Please note that their flash message is in the main layout (shared across all views), not part of the login page. (https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example/blob/master/index.html#L14)

Comment: still i am getting the same error ..plz give me some suggestion...i am waiting for your positive reply.

Comment: sorry @SugyanSwain, I'm not sure what you're doing or not doing. there are a million things that could be failing in your app, including the communication with the remote endpoint. i suggest you clone the `angular-registration-login-example` and play with it before trying to hand-pick components from it.